# TFS Query for showing all Bugs per test case and task

Tags: tfs

I'm having a hard time defining my query in TSF 2013. I want it to show all bugs in a project, sorted in a tree structure per test case and task. Something like this:

```
TaskName1
    TestCaseName1
        BugName2
        BugName3
    TestCaseName4
        BugName5
        BugName6
TaskName7
    TestCaseName8
        BugName9
    TestCaseName10
        BugName11
        BugName12
        etc...
```

Currently, a task is the parent and the test case is the child (One-to-many) and each bug is related to a test case (many-to-many). There are no direct links between bugs and associated tasks. Only indirect, through the test case.

Any experts on TFS queries that could help me with this? Is it even possible, given the current relationships between the different Work Items?

Thank you.

Comment: @Daniel Mann I've managed to filter the bugs per test cases but not with the tasks. Like this:


    TestCaseName1
        BugName2
        BugName3
    TestCaseName4
        BugName5
        etc...

To this end, i used "Work items and direct links". I'll give "Tree of work items" a try.

Comment: It depends on the link types between the Work Items.  I'm guessing they are not all Parent-Child (probably Tested By for Test Cases) which means a Tree query isn't going to do the job.  That said, your hierarchy seems odd to me.  I'd expect to see Bugs and PBIs/User Stories at the top level on your backlog with child Tasks.  Test Cases would be linked to the top level items rather than the Tasks in order to ensure the Acceptance Criteria for each item is satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the advise from rerwinRR and re-structured the TFS. The bugs are now User Stories. This has simplified the organisation of bugs immensely. Thanks!